# Django generating spreadsheet with right extension

Tags: django, xls

I have these lines below to generate a spreadsheet

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/xlsx')
file_name = ('filename=%s.xls' % datetime.datetime.now())
response['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment;%s' % file_name)
writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';')
```

The file extension does not open as xlsx, but rather as csv.
ideas?

Comment: You are writing a csv using `csv.writer`. The extension `xls` is a matter of what your machine will use to open the file. Try to `open-with` your file with Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options you an use openpyxl or pandas XlsxWriter/ExcelWriter. Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial) on both